# Get day from day number of the year?

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

How to write a program that asks the user the day number in year in the range 2 to 365 and asks the first day of year -
 Sunday, Monday or Tuesday etc. Then program should display the day-number that has been input.

For example:

```
Input year = 2019

Input of day number = 144

First day of year = 'Tuesday'

Output = 'Friday' (-> 144th day of year 2019 = Friday)
```

Note:- you can not use "Date" and "Month" of that particular year

From this [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/blog/developers/how-to-find-the-day-of-a-week/) of an algorithm, I tried to finding out day by using this as reference but could not find particular solution:

```
def day_of_week(year, month, day):
    t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
    year -= month < 3
    return (year + int(year/4) - int(year/100) + int(year/400) + t[month-1] 
            + day) % 7

day = 28

month = 4

year = 2019


print(day_of_week(year, month, day))
```

Comment: This seems like a homework :). Please show some code

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I understand you right...the program takes the year, the first day of the year (e.g. 'Tuesday'), and a number (e.g. 144), and it just outputs the day of the week corresponding to that number day in the year (e.g. 'Friday is the 144th day of 2019)?

If that's the problem, simply use mod by 7 to find the answer, like so:

```
def numberedDay(firstDay, dayNumber):
    days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    firstIndex = days.index(firstDay)
    endIndex = (firstIndex + int(dayNumber) - 1) % 7
    return days[endIndex]


year = input("Year: ")
firstDay = input("First day of the year (e.g. 'Monday'): ")
dayNumber = input("Day number: ")

print(numberedDay(firstDay, dayNumber))
```

Comment: You don't even need to ask for first day of the year: `firstIndex = datetime.datetime(YEAR, 1, 1).weekday()`

Answer (score 0):

But as per condition of 'dayNumber' , it shoud be in the range between 2 to 365. I think this might be work...

```
# Solution - 2 With dayNumber in the Range betwwen 2 to 365...


import sys
def numberedDay(firstDay, dayNumber):
   #firstDay = 'Wednesday'
   #dayNumber = 319

   # Made weekly days dictionary 
   days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 
   'Sunday']
   # Automatically generate first index of days dictionary.. For example if firstDay 
   = 'Wednesday' then it will return firstDay=2
   firstIndex = days.index(firstDay)
   # Generating endIndex....
   endIndex = (firstIndex + int(dayNumber) - 1) % 7
   # endIndex = (2 + int(dayNumber) - 1) % 7
   # endIndex = (2 + 319 - 1) % 7
   # endIndex = (320) % 7
   # endIndex =  5

   return days[endIndex]
   # return 5th element of days list which is = Saturday

# Input Year = 1997
year = input("Year: ")
# Input firstDay = Wednesday
firstDay = input("First day of the year (e.g. 'Monday'): ")
# Input dayNumber = 319
dayNumber = input("Day number: ")

#if int(dayNumber) > 365:
#    raise sys.exit()


if int(dayNumber) in range(2,365): 
   # printing dayNumber given by user
   dayNumber = int(dayNumber)

else:
   # if dayNumber is greater than 365 then system will be exit.
   raise sys.exit()

# printing output
print(numberedDay(firstDay, dayNumber))
```